# Is the electrophile in sulfonation of benzene SO3 or SO3H+?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

What's the electrophile in sulfonation of benzene? Is it $\ce{SO3}$ or $\ce{SO3H+}$?

According to what my professor taught me, both $\ce{SO3}$ and $\ce{SO3H+}$ may be the electrophile involved - and mechanisms with both species can be successfully written.

I'm looking for some source(s) that confirms the existence of both electrophiles in sulfonation reaction of benzene.

Comment: SO3H+ seriously? That's equal to Lewis superacid able to bind almost anything, and even best non-coordinating anions would probably fail to keep separate from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Clayden, under the heading "Sulfonation of Benzene" (electrophilic aromatic substitution):

> The cationic intermediate can
>   also be formed by the protonation
>   of sulfur trioxide, $\ce{SO3}$, and
>   another way to do sulfonations is
>   to use concentrated sulfuric acid
>   with $\ce{SO3}$ added. These solutions
>   have the industrial name *oleum*.
>   It is possible that the sulfonating
>   agent in all these reactions is not
>   protonated $\ce{SO3}$ but $\ce{SO3}$ itself.

[image]

From March's $7^{th}$ edition, under *Sulfur electrophiles*:

> Sulfonation is often accomplished with concentrated sulfuric acid, but it can also be
>   done with fuming sulfuric acid, $\ce{SO3}, \ce{ClSO2OH}, \ce{ClSO2NMe2/In(OTf)3}$ or other reagents.
>
> Sulfur trioxide reacts much more rapidly
>   than sulfuric acid with benzene it is nearly instantaneous
>
> A great deal of work has been done on the mechanism, chiefly by Cerfontain
>   and co-workers. Mechanistic study is made difficult by the complicated nature of
>   the solutions. Indications are that the electrophile varies with the reagent, though
>   $\ce{SO3}$ is involved in all cases, either free or combined with a carrier. In aqueous
>   $\ce{H2SO4}$ solutions, the electrophile is thought to be $\ce{H3SO4+}$
>   (or a combination of
>   $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{H3O+}$) at concentrations below $\sim 80–85%$ $\ce{H2SO4}$, and $\ce{H2S2O7}$ (or a
>   combination of $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{SO3}$) at concentrations higher than this. (the changeover
>   point varies with the substrate)
>
> In fuming sulfuric acid ($\ce{H2SO4}$ containing
>   excess $\ce{SO3}$), the electrophile is thought to be $\ce{H3S2O7+}$
>   (protonated $\ce{H2S2O7}$) up to $\sim 104% \ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{H2S4O13} (\ce{H2SO4+ 3SO3})$ beyond this concentration.
>
> Finally, when pure $\ce{SO3}$ is the reagent in aprotic solvents, $\ce{SO3}$ itself is the actual
>   electrophile. Free $\ce{SO3}$ is the most reactive of all these species, so that attack
>   here is generally fast and a subsequent step is usually rate determining, at least
>   in some solvents.